# Resource files (image, css, js etc) does not loading when play application deployed as war

Tags: playframework

I am using play framwork. I have created war of my project with play war [project] -o [war name]. It got successful but during running the image, css and js are not loaded as all the content were placed into WEB-INF folder.

Can anyone help me out how to use/create war so that it can be use.

Comment: How are you referencing your content files? Are you using the @{} syntax, or are you just using a plain path?

Comment: its just a plain path, although i tried with @{} too.. :(

Comment: Can you see what is wrong with the url of the images in the generated html?

Comment: I have looked into the URL its fine as its working fine with play's default server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar problem with images in .css file. When war was deployed pictures were invisible. Below is my solution:

1.In **routes** file you should have this line:

```
GET         /assets/*file       controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

with your actual path to .css .js and images.

2.You should include **.css** files in this way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")">
```

3.**Java script** should be referenced into Play! template in following way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/myscript.js")"></script>
```

4.**A picture** in .css should be referenced using relative path since .css file is placed into assests\ as well as images:

```
.checked-partial {
    background-image: url("../images/partial.png");
}
```

5.After that you can create war as you've mantioned: *play war*

If you configure .css, .js, and images this way it will work on Play! web-server as well as on other web-server with your war.